# How to get csv row count in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2, csvhelper

Im working with CsvHelper for my Asp.net Core 2.2 MVC EF Application. I can read the data and insert it to my database after I upload the csv comma delimited file. but when the csv file has many rows inside, it only insert the first row and even if the csv has 10 rows inside. below is my Controller code:
I hope you can help me. TIA.

```
[HttpPost("textCsv")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> textCsv([Bind("CompanyCode,ProductCode,TransactionDate,TransactionTime,OriginatingBranch,CustomerNumber,TransactionOrigin,TypeOfPayment,CheckNumber,TransactionAmount,CustomerName,UserName,UserIP,UserDate")]BdoToDb bdoToDb, List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            UserDetails();
            long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

            // full path to file in temp location
            var filepath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var users = new List<BDOCsv>();
            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var stream = formFile.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        try { users = stream.CsvToList<BDOCsv>(); }
                        catch (Exception ex) { return BadRequest(ex.Message); }
                    }
                }
            }
            int i = 0;
            while (i < users.Count)
            {
                ViewBag.CompanyCode = users[i].CompanyCode;
                ViewBag.ProductCode = users[i].ProductCode;
                ViewBag.TransactionDate = users[i].TransactionDate;
                ViewBag.TransactionTime = users[i].TransactionTime;
                ViewBag.OriginatingBranch = users[i].OriginatingBranch;
                ViewBag.CustomerNumber = users[i].CustomerNumber;
                ViewBag.TransactionOrigin = users[i].TransactionOrigin;
                ViewBag.TypeOfPayment = users[i].TypeOfPayment;
                ViewBag.CheckNumber = users[i].CheckNumber;
                ViewBag.TransactionAmount = users[i].TransactionAmount;
                ViewBag.CustomerName = users[i].CustomerName;

                bdoToDb.CompanyCode = ViewBag.CompanyCode;
                bdoToDb.ProductCode = ViewBag.ProductCode;
                bdoToDb.TransactionDate = ViewBag.TransactionDate;
                bdoToDb.TransactionTime = ViewBag.TransactionTime;
                bdoToDb.OriginatingBranch = ViewBag.OriginatingBranch;
                bdoToDb.CustomerNumber = ViewBag.CustomerNumber;
                bdoToDb.TransactionOrigin = ViewBag.TransactionOrigin;
                bdoToDb.TypeOfPayment = ViewBag.TypeOfPayment;
                bdoToDb.CheckNumber = ViewBag.CheckNumber;
                bdoToDb.TransactionAmount = ViewBag.TransactionAmount;
                bdoToDb.CustomerName = ViewBag.CustomerName;
                bdoToDb.UserName = ViewBag.DisplayName;
                bdoToDb.UserIP = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
                bdoToDb.UserDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                i++;
                _context.Add(bdoToDb);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            //return View();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Comment: Hello, I am looking at this  function. Can you share how to do this completely?

Comment: Hi @Haohao1198, you can check it here https://github.com/josebalerosjr/Intranet on my repo. its in the Intranet > Controllers > BdoPEController

Comment: Hello,@Jose Baleros Jr , thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
try { users = stream.CsvToList<BDOCsv>(); }
```

overwrites the `users` list every time it reads a file. So when you do

```
while (i < users.Count)
```

the `users` list only contains the last user file that was read in.

Try changing it to

```
try { users.AddRange(stream.CsvToList<BDOCsv>(); }
```

This will append the new users to the existing list, instead of replacing them.

Comment: Hi Sir @Simple Ged, thank you for this answer, this now get the row count but I've encounter another error on the last part of the code `i++;
                _context.Add(bdoToDb);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` after the first loop an error occurs that says the identity insert is set to off.

Comment: @josebalerosjr Can you please create a new question regarding your new problem. Make sure you create a [mcve] for your problem and not post all of the code (you may find when you create a [mcve] you solve the problem yourself :-) )